# Data didnt coming from api.Javascript doesnt work on html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have some problems. i should present on html file data. Data coming from api.And i append to data to array.On blogs i should show article image and title.But didnt add. Where is my mistake. Please help me

```
const blogs = {
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
  blogs: () => {
    let blogData = $(".blog_area").serializeArray();
    let blogArray = {};
    if (blogData) {
      blogArray.id = blogData[0].value;
      blogArray.image = blogData[1].value;
      blogArray.title = blogData[2].value;
      blogArray.article=blogData[3].value;
      console.log(blogArray)
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", blog.baseURL + "blog/allblog", true);
      request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
      request.send(JSON.stringify(blogArray));
      
      request.onload = () => {
        if (request.status != 400 && request.status != 500) {
    console.log(blogArray);
           col = $("<div>");
           col.addClass("blog-content col-md-9");
           $(".blog-content").attr("id");
           $(".blog-content").attr("image");
           $(".blog-content").attr("title");
           $(".blog-content").attr("article");
           col.append(image);
           col.append(article);
           col.append(id);
           console.log("salam");
           col.append(title);
console.log(blogArray);
        

        } else {
          console.log("You didnt get ");
        }
      };
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your JS handling the DOM.

How far along do you get in your console.logs?

I am reading that you are creating a div but not appending it to the document.

At the end of the DOM manipulation you should bind your div to some element.

`document.querySelector(".elementToBindTo").appendChild(col);`

From your approach it is unclear what title is.
`col.append(title);`

Possibly title is an element. But I don't see the declaration in your example. It could be :

```
const table = document.querySelector("table");
table.append(col)
```